# BigInteger.ToString("x") doesn't properly print negative hex numbers

Tags: c#, .net, tostring, biginteger

I need to print out a BigInteger as a negative number, however the Hex overload of ToString("X") is incorrect.

```
        BigInteger be1 = new BigInteger();
        be1 = 0x7e;
        Console.WriteLine(be1.ToString());     // 126
        Console.WriteLine(be1.ToString("X"));  // 7E
        Console.WriteLine(be1.ToString("x"));  // 7e
        Console.WriteLine();
        be1 = BigInteger.Negate(be1);  
        Console.WriteLine(be1.ToString());     // -126  OK
        Console.WriteLine(be1.ToString("X"));  // 82  WRONG
        Console.WriteLine(be1.ToString("x"));  // 82 WRONG
```

Am I doing something wrong, how can I fix this?

(For what it's worth I'm doing this so I can [match the hex output here, illustrated as an C++ array](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bignum.h#L362))

Comment: It's not really wrong assuming a 8 bit number. -1 = 0xff, -128 = 0x80, -127 = 0x81, -126 as shown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ToString` prints a hexadecimal integer as if it were unsigned. To print it hexadecimal with a sign, negate the value and prefix it with a sign.

```
BigInteger v = new BigInteger(-10);
string str = "-" + (-v).ToString("X");  // "-0A"
```

As an extension method, it could work like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BigInteger v = new BigInteger(-10);
        Console.WriteLine(v.ToSignedHexString());   // Prints: "-0A"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class BigIntegerExtensions
{
    public static string ToSignedHexString(this BigInteger value)
    {
        if (value.Sign == -1)
            return "-" + (-value).ToString("X");
        else
            return value.ToString("X");
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem being that this will crash if `v` is equal to `int.MinValue`.

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't crash, but the results will be unexpected because `-Int.MinValue == Int.MinValue`. And, yeah ... this won't be an issue with `BigInteger`.

Comment: @JimMischel Actually, on second thought, with integers it will work just as well. For `Int32.MinValue` the algorithm would print `-80000000`, which is correct and not at all unexpected. If you were to cast it all to `long` you'd get the exact same result for `Int32.MinValue`.

Answer (score 2):

The hex format output for numbers is never negative for C#.

This applies to ints too - for example,

```
int x = -1000;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("X"));
```

outputs

```
FFFFFC18
```

Comment: Also (referring to the value of the question) `((sbyte)(-126)).ToString("X")` gives `"82"`, and `((short)(-126)).ToString("X")` gives `"FF82"`, and `(-126).ToString("X")` gives `"FFFFFF82"`, and finally `(-126L).ToString("X")` gives `"FFFFFFFFFFFFFF82"`. So with fixed-width integer types, we get padded with `F`s as necessary to signify a negative value. For `BigInteger`, that would be an infinite prefix of `F`s which is not possible. So here we just include an `F` if the leading hex digit would otherwise be in the interval `0` through `7`.

Comment: And posive values may need a leading `0` in their hex formatting output, as in `((BigInteger)11).ToString("X")` which must give `"0B"`, not just `"B"`.

Answer (score 1):

hex can't be negative. So use Math.Sign and Math.Abs :

```
        int v = -126;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", v, (Math.Sign(v) < 0 ? "-" : String.Empty) + Math.Abs(v).ToString("X"));
```